# Interpolation for a Dataframe without explicit 'NaN' rows in the original Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering how I could interpolate between rows for the column 'Data' where I loop through it and create a new row with '0.3', '0.5' and '0.6' to fill in the gaps?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0.1,0.2,0.4,0.7],columns=['Data'])
df
```

[image]

How do I do this with code to the original dataframe to produce the image below?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? Given a dataframe (that consists of only a single column?), create new rows so that the values in subsequent rows are at most 0.1 apart? You might be able to just do `df.Data = np.arange(df.Data.min(), df.Data.max(), 0.1)` if that's all you want. If there _are_ other columns, how should those be handled? Do you put NaN in for other columns on the interpolated rows?

Comment: Yes NaNs are fine in the other columns.

Comment: I think your first line of code is the answer 'np.arange(df.Data.min(),df.Data.max() +0.1,0.1)

Comment: I just added the 0.1 to include the 0.7

Comment: This is more like recreate the data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there should be 2 solutions, also added more columns to sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [0.1,0.2,0.4,0.7],
                   'A':list('abcd'),
                   'B':[4,5,6,9]})
print (df)
   Data  A  B
0   0.1  a  4
1   0.2  b  5
2   0.4  c  6
3   0.7  d  9
```

Create index by `Data` column and use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
arr = np.arange(df.Data.min(),df.Data.max() + 0.1,0.1)

df1 = df.set_index('Data').reindex(arr).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Data    A    B
0   0.1    a  4.0
1   0.2    b  5.0
2   0.3  NaN  NaN
3   0.4    c  6.0
4   0.5  NaN  NaN
5   0.6  NaN  NaN
6   0.7  NaN  NaN
```

Or create helper `DataFrame` and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data':arr}).merge(df, how='left')
print (df1)
   Data    A    B
0   0.1    a  4.0
1   0.2    b  5.0
2   0.3  NaN  NaN
3   0.4    c  6.0
4   0.5  NaN  NaN
5   0.6  NaN  NaN
6   0.7  NaN  NaN
```